# Track activities and changes that were made in civicrm by staff

Tags: contacts, activities, admin

What is the best way to track what changes that a staff member has made in civicrm? I am trying to track activities and changes that were made in civicrm by staff.

Answer (score 1):

Under administer - system settings - misc you can turn on logging which tracks changes.

Also if using drupal turning on the statistics module is sometimes helpful in seeing what people have been clicking on since it makes a recent hits report available.

Comment: As a note @WVMike - turning on the logging requires permissions that many shared hosting providers don't give you.  If this is a need and you don't have appropriate hosting, consider moving to a virtual private server (VPS) provider.